# manage different versions of software in bitbucket

Tags: version-control, mercurial, bitbucket

I need to create a branch or fork for the new version of the software in bitbucket using mercurial. The main branch should be the version 2.0 branch, accessible as the default branch without specifying its name, while 1.0 should be accessible for bug fixes by giving branch name. These would never merge. Multiple people will be working on both the branches. How do i achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

**READ HG-BOOK!**. After reading and understanding:

1. Don't mix Git-style with Mercurial way
2. Don't mix remote's path name with branch's name (and usage of remotes and branches in Mercurial)
3. Use default `default` branch as main branch and create one more branch, name it as you want